# Angular saves the first route and reuses

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-router, routereusestrategy

I have two pages: **login** and **account**.
There are two scenarios:

1. first route is `/login`
2. first route is `/account`

First route is when, for example, I open chrome and type `localhost:8100/login` `/login` would be the first route.

First scenario, when first route is `/login`:

- user is currently at `/login`;
- user loggs in to *account1* and now user is at `/account`;
- `/account` shows *account1* data;
- user loggs out and goes back to `/login`;
- user loggs in to *account2* goes to `/account`;
- `/account` show *account2* data as it should.

Second scenario, when first route is `/account`:

- user is currently at `/account` and is logged in to *account1*;
- user loggs out and goes to `/login`;
- user loggs in to *account2* and goes back to `/account`;
- `/account` shows *account1* data instead of *account2* and the ngOnInit was not called.

I'm guessing, the problem is when the first route is `/account` it is saved, and reused by Angular.

I have implemented a custom route reuse strategy, it works perfectly. I set `/account` route to not be reused by the strategy. And it is not, it is not saved in *storedRoutes*, variable where saved routes are. But it is reused anyway. Same thing with `/login` route: when `/login` route is the first route it is saved, not by my custom RRS, and angular reuses it.

this is the custom route reuse strategy:

```
class CustomRouteReuseStrategy implements RouteReuseStrategy {

    /** 
     * Object which will store RouteStorageObjects indexed by keys
     * The keys will all be a path (as in route.routeConfig.path)
     * This allows us to see if we've got a route stored for the requested path
     */
    storedRoutes: { [key: string]: RouteStorageObject } = {};

    /** 
     * Decides when the route should be stored
     * If the route should be stored, I believe the boolean is indicating to a controller whether or not to fire this.store
     * _When_ it is called though does not particularly matter, just know that this determines whether or not we store the route
     * An idea of what to do here: check the route.routeConfig.path to see if it is a path you would like to store
     * @param route This is, at least as I understand it, the route that the user is currently on, and we would like to know if we want to store it
     * @returns boolean indicating that we want to (true) or do not want to (false) store that route
     */
    shouldDetach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
        const detach: boolean = route.data.routeReuse === true;

        return detach;
    }

    /**
     * Constructs object of type `RouteStorageObject` to store, and then stores it for later attachment
     * @param route This is stored for later comparison to requested routes, see `this.shouldAttach`
     * @param handle Later to be retrieved by this.retrieve, and offered up to whatever controller is using this class
     */
    store(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, handle: DetachedRouteHandle): void {
        const storedRoute: RouteStorageObject = {
            snapshot: route,
            handle: handle
        };

        // routes are stored by path - the key is the path name, and the handle is stored under it so that you can only ever have one object stored for a single path
        this.storedRoutes[route.routeConfig.path] = storedRoute;
    }

    /**
    * Determines whether or not there is a stored route and, if there is, whether or not it should be rendered in place of requested route
    * @param route The route the user requested
    * @returns boolean indicating whether or not to render the stored route
    */
    shouldAttach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {

        // this will be true if the route has been stored before
        const canAttach: boolean = !!route.routeConfig && !!this.storedRoutes[route.routeConfig.path];

        // this decides whether the route already stored should be rendered in place of the requested route, and is the return value
        // at this point we already know that the paths match because the storedResults key is the route.routeConfig.path
        // so, if the route.params and route.queryParams also match, then we should reuse the component
        if (canAttach) {
            const willAttach: boolean = true;

            const paramsMatch: boolean = this.compareObjects(route.params, this.storedRoutes[route.routeConfig.path].snapshot.params);
            const queryParamsMatch: boolean = this.compareObjects(route.queryParams, this.storedRoutes[route.routeConfig.path].snapshot.queryParams);

            return paramsMatch && queryParamsMatch;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /** 
    * Finds the locally stored instance of the requested route, if it exists, and returns it
    * @param route New route the user has requested
    * @returns DetachedRouteHandle object which can be used to render the component
    */
    retrieve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): DetachedRouteHandle {

        // return null if the path does not have a routerConfig OR if there is no stored route for that routerConfig
        if (!route.routeConfig || !this.storedRoutes[route.routeConfig.path]) return null;
        
        /** returns handle when the route.routeConfig.path is already stored */
        return this.storedRoutes[route.routeConfig.path].handle;
    }

    /** 
    * Determines whether or not the current route should be reused
    * @param future The route the user is going to, as triggered by the router
    * @param curr The route the user is currently on
    * @returns boolean basically indicating true if the user intends to leave the current route
    */
    shouldReuseRoute(future: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, curr: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
        return future.routeConfig === curr.routeConfig;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would honestly expect your authentification to be faulty.
E.g. when you klick your "log in" button you might fetch cached login-information and therefore have all your infos for account1 shown. Would you mind sharing the code where you handle the account information?

Comment: This. your not clear local storage or something.